# Finding Min Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, diagonalization

I have the upper triangular matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 32 & \ast & \dots & \ast\\
    0 & 1 & \ast & \dots & \ast\\
    0 & 0 &  21 & \dots & \ast \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ast\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \ast \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

where $\ast$ represents any number.

I know $A$ is not diagonalisable, and want to prove $(x-1)^2$ divides the minimum polynomial, $m_A(x)$, for $A$.

I know $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if $m_A(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors. Hence $m_A(x)$ is not the product of distinct linear factors.

I also know that $m_A(x)$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Hence $m_A(x)$ divides $(x-1)^2f(x)$.

Are these two facts enough to prove that $(x-1)^2$ must divide $m_A(x)$? I am unsure whether $f(x)$ may contain the repeated linear factors?